# when i call my function metamask telling "this operation is expected to fail"

Tags: hash, string, keccak

Hi guys im trying to create question challenge dapp and i have a `checkAnswer()` function can accessable from frontend.
My question struct:

```
    struct Question{
        string qDesc;
        uint qPrize;//must be wei
        uint qDate;
        string[3] qHints;
        string qAnswer;
        bool qState;
        bool qWait;
    }
```

Part of function body:

```
    function checkAnswer(string memory _answer) public payable{
     if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(newQuestion.qAnswer)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_answer))){
      ...
     }
     ...
    }
```

When i sent "test answer" input value to function it's successfully calls. But when i trying send "test cevap" value to function, metamask gives me "this operation is expected to fail". What's happening here i don't understand.

Comment: I tried a lot of variation it's giving error only when i type "test cevap" to input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is corrupting my function. When user sends right answer to function, smart contract was transferring challenge prize to `msg.sender` but I don't have enough balance in contract wallet so this is why corrupted transaction.